# Django - how to go back to previous view with parameters

Tags: django

I am relatively new with Django, this must be a common problem.
I have created a view to show a form to input date (using widget that returns separate fields):
when date is inserted, I call a function userPage(request, my_date)
that filters, processes and renders a page (user.html) showing a list of items.

```
def datePage(request):
    user=request.user
    context = {}
    context['form'] = UserDateForm()
    if request.GET:
        date_yr = request.GET['food_date_year']
        date_mo = request.GET['food_date_month']
        date_day = request.GET['food_date_day']
        my_date_string = date_yr+'-'+date_mo+'-'+date_day
        my_date = datetime.strptime(my_date_string, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
        return userPage(request,my_date)
    return render(request, "date.html", context)

def userPage(request, my_date):
    user=request.user
    # process context using user, my_date

    context={...:..., 'my_date': my_date}
    return render(request,'user.html',context)
```

In user.html I include a URL to add an item:

```
    </div>
    <form action="{% url 'My_ItemCreate' %}" method="POST">
        {%csrf_token%}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </button>
    </form> 
</div>
```

'My_ItemCreate' points to a django.views.generic CreateView that creates an item.:

```
    path('MyItemCreate/',views.My_ItemCreate.as_view(),name='My_ItemCreate'),

class My_ItemCreate(CreateView):
    model = MyItem
    fields = ...
```

1. After creating the item in the CreateView, how do I go back to the user page
   after I inserted the date? I have lost the date in the new URL.
   If I use URL resolver to go to  userPage, how do I pass a date in the format?
2. It would be nice that I am able to pass initial values in the CreateView, and
   make some fields read-only, how do I modify/override CreateView ?

Many Thanks for your help!

Comment: It will help if you provide a more complete code example. You mention `My_ItemCreate`, but don't show the code for it. Also give the `urlpatterns` to go along with the description.

Comment: With that said, I would look into using [`redirect()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) or [`HTTPResponseRedirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect) to redirect to the URL you want.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice 
I have added the code for My_ItemCreate, thanks !   
I have solved problem 1) saving the date in request.session and retrieving it in  
 userPage view.   
In this way I do not need to pass 'date' to user page and I do not 
need to redirect at all, it works fine.   
Still not sure how to manipulate fields (initial values, read-only) shown in a CreateView  
do I need to use another type of view?    
Many thanks again
D

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer to my problem: using request.session
to store a value and retrieving in other views, it works fine.

I am still curious to know if there are experts who
would provide a more elegant solution, and if someone
could be so kind to answer point 2) regarding CreateView read_only fields
Thanks
D

Comment: Using a session for this will break people using multiple tabs.